# How to get real host or server name in PHP

Tags: php

How can I get real host name by not using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in PHP? Is there other more reliable way to get it ?

I have created a function which gets host name from the path to the domain.

I would like to avoid using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable, because it can be faked by sending modified headers in the HTTP request.

This is my current implementation (this works if the path has an actual domain name in it. For instance: /vhosts/website.com/public_html):

```
function getServerName() {
 $path = realpath(__FILE__);
 $url = array();
 preg_match_all("/\/[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+/i", $path, $url);
 // 4 is minimum requirement for the address (e.g: http://www.in.tv)
 if (strlen($url[0][0]) > 4) {
  $result = str_replace("/", "", $url[0][0]);
  return $result;
 }
 else
  return false;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: More probably he doesn't know how to properly express his question. It would be nice to help newbies and explain what he misunderstood in the provided environment and HTTP protocol instead of voting his question down.

Comment: You know what, fine. I'll fix the question. The problem is that half the stuff he is saying I don't get, and can only make inferences about what he is talking about. I can only assume 'PATH' means 'SCRIPT_PATH', and I can't tell if he is talking about 'HTTP_HOST' or 'SERVER_NAME'. It seems hard to believe that he could have written a script, yet not know which variables he is using.

Comment: @Chacha102 yeah I know, I hear the same questions over and over again from my work mates... ;-) I just posted a longer answer in the hope the next "information seeker" can more easy find it. Hope dies last? ;-)

Comment: Eh, nvm. I won't edit it main because he doesn't know what variables he is talking about, and thus I can't reliably fix the question.

Comment: @minnur Please fix your original question... (the hash indices of $\_SERVER seem to be incorrect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: as pointed by Gumbo, the original poster probably means HTTP_HOST rather than HOST_NAME. Otherwise, my answer is plain wrong.*

The HTTP_HOST variable reflects the domain name that the visitor used to access the site. If doesn't have anything to do with file paths! Its value is conveniently stored in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Is there any other way to get it? Of course, there're normally several ways to do things. For instance, this works when PHP runs as Apache module.

```
<?php

$request_headers = apache_request_headers();
echo $request_headers['Host'];

?>
```

The question is: why would anyone want to do such a thing? Why replace a reliable standard method with a quirky workaround that eventually fetches the same piece of data from the same place?

You have the concern that $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is altered by the HTTP request. Of course it is: that's where it comes from. The browser has to specify what site it wants to visit (that's the base of name based virtual hosts) and if it sends a rogue value, well, it just won't reach the site.

Comment: There is no `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']`; it’s `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: The main problem the OP probably had with his hosting is that it's a managed standard apache/plesk/whatever installation which always responds with the first vhost no matter which host name is sent if that doesn't match any of the vhosts. Proper way to fix that would be to return 404 if the http host from the request headers doesn't match what is expected. Otherwise you won't make anything better (in the sense what you are trying to fix/prevent).

Answer (score 7):

If you want a server name that can't be set by the client, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. It is set by the server itself **but can also be forged under certain circumstances** using a bug, as Gumbo points out and links to in the comments.

Comment: In fact it can be manipulated by the client (see http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host).

Comment: @Gumbo: That was a bug.  Whether it's still present or not, I don't know (that blog entry is nearly 4 years old)

Comment: @R. Bemrose: It *is* still present (PHP 5.3.0).

Comment: @Gumbo: Good to know! I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Some things will never change … ;-) But I don’t know if it’s really a bug. Maybe that behavior is on purpose.

Comment: I think this is a flaw in apache's vhost design and how "UseCanonicalName off" works - which shouldn't be used anyway except your REALLY know the consequences (eg SERVER_NAME being set by Http-Request-Host instead of from the vhost config, which actually can be set to any string as it is client-provided). Apparently it is a (dangerous) default setting in many of the managed deployments out there.

Answer (score 5):

I think the one you are referring to is

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

which, given the HTTP prefix means it comes from the HTTP Headers.

You might want to use:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

which is defined by the server and can't be changed via a request?

Comment: SERVER_NAME -> can it or can it not be modified via a request?

Answer (score 4):

this will get the hostname server-side, but if you're running on a commercial host (not hosting yourself), I don't imagine this will be all that useful.

```
$host = php_uname( 'n' );
```

If you're using Apache, what you should do is make your server / site only answer to certain names (else there should be a default that doesn't do much).  You can do with with the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives.

Comment: if you only ever use a whitelist of hostnames, you'll never get injected

Answer (score 2):

Of course `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` can be modified by the client - because in fact **IT IS** sent by the client. This is part of the http protocol. If you want to get the primary server name defined in the vhost configuration of apache or whatever you can access `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` as proposed by the others.

I suggest it is not wise to extract the domain name from the file path of the server (which is stored in `__FILE__`) as it may render your application non-relocatable (it will no longer be storage location agnostic).

You may see the contents of the array by dumping it within the script using `var_dump($_SERVER)` but keep in mind the not all web servers and all web server settings expose the same environment. This is documented in the web server documentation and I think it is partly documented in the php online docs.

**Update / Important notice:** As others pointed out, the content of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` could be spoofed if apache is configured for `UseCanonicalName off` (which may be a default setting if you are using eg Plesk-based hosting). So actually going with the `__FILE__` can solve this (if your doc root contains the host name). The bigger problem of the first approach is that it can be used to inject any sort of stuff into your application (SQL, JavaScript) because php programmers usually take it granted that `SERVER_NAME` is no user input and thus apply no sanitizing to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will use $path = realpath(__FILE__);

Answer (score 1):

You don't. That's the purpose of the $_SERVER variables. If you want to get the HOST_NAME from the path, you must first get the PATH from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: Thanks, everyone. That's all what i wanted to know.