# How to retrieve the HOSTNAME of your site

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm fiddling with php environment variables and I just installed php8.0 and want to know how to retrieve the hostname of my site.

The code I'm running is:

```
echo 'This is your HOSTNAME: %s, $(ENV['HOSTNAME']);
```

Can anyone steer my in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136914/how-to-get-real-host-or-server-name-in-php

Comment: I see Samuel. I was looking for the $_ENV['HOSTNAME']; method. The $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; is practically the same. Thanks Samuel!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get real host or server name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136914/how-to-get-real-host-or-server-name-in-php)